# JPA Specification in Quarkus

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, quarkus, specifications

I am currently migrating a SpringBoot project to Quarkus where I use the JpaSpecificationExecutor interface to create dynamic querys. I see [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8136) that Quarkus still has no support for this kind of feature so I wanted to know if is there any recommendation on alternatives for this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A few months later after I posted this question I can say that I solved this problem by migrating all of my old specifications the **JPA Criteria API**.

You can find several examples online on how to use this API. The syntax is pretty similar to Specifications.